# Why "strict" testing when undefined vs false

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```js
function doit() {
  var current_mods = {
    alt: false,
    shift: false
  };

  var required_mods = {};

  for (var modname in current_mods) {
    if (current_mods[modname] != required_mods[modname]) {
      alert('mismatch');
      return;
    }
  }

  alert('matched');
}
doit();
```

It keeps telling me mismatch. But I am not doing `!==`, shouldn't `undefined != false` return false, as they are both falsey?

Comment: They are not both falsey. Undifined equals nothing, does even not equal to undefined

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvoted. It's perfectly well written

Comment: You have too much reputation on this site for such a basic question that could have been answered by typing `undefined == false` in your browser console...

Comment: Ah, @AndréDion, I see now

Comment: Thanks @bug I didn't realize that about `undefined == undefined` wow!

Comment: @bub they are indeed both "falsy", but that doesn't matter. Under the rules for `==`, `undefined is `==` to itself and to `null`.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for `==` and `!=` comparison state that a comparison of two values of different types when one of them is boolean should be done by converting the boolean to a number and then proceeding. Thus your `false` is converted to `0` and the comparison is treated as if it were

```
undefined != 0
```

That, in turn, falls off the end of the comparison process to the default result of `false`.

Testing an object property value is a process complicated by the fact that an expression like `obj[prop]` will evaluate to `undefined` when the property is not present at all, or when the property *is* present but has no value. Depending on your needs, you can use the `in` operator in conjunction with a value test:

```
  if (modname in required_mods) {
    if (current_mods[modname] !== required_mods[modname])
      alert("value mismatch");
  }
  else
    alert("property " + modname + " missing");
```

Comment: @Noitidart and note that `undefined == undefined` is `true`, as is `undefined == null`.

Comment: Thanks pointy for that note, I just tested it and realized. So for my above case, the if I should use is this: `if (!current_mods[modname] != !required_mods[modname]) {`

Comment: @Noitidart that might work. For testing to see if an object contains a property, you can use the `in` operator: `if (modname in current_mods ...`

Comment: `if (!!current_mods[modname] != !!required_mods[modname])`

Comment: Thanks Pointy, but in my situation if falsey, it may not be in there, it might be in there but undefined, or it might be in there as false. Thanks @AlekseyL. the double neg is interesting can you please explain why that works and not the single neg?

Comment: @Noitidart `!!` casts to _boolean_

Comment: @Pointy may you please include Aleksy's solution to my test case above, i honestly didn't know about it :) If you don't mind. Thanks!

Comment: @Noitidart well, I'm not sure that's a good solution; `!!` will convert all truthy values to `true`, and that doesn't seem like the goal you had for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Both values are falsey does not necessary mean they are equal.

According to the ECMAScript specification (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), `undefined` is not equal to `false`.